# Deploying feathersjs app with mongodb

Tags: mongodb, heroku, mlab, feathersjs

I am trying to deploy my feathersJS app on heroku with mongodb database. I used mLab sandbox plan, I did not configure anything on it. But as there is no documentation or any previous questions about it here I am.
I have made a feathersJS app running with mongodb. But when I deploy it on heroku I always get an error 503, service unavaible (timeout). 
Here is in /config/default.json

```
"mongodb": "mongodb://localhost:27017/api_feathers",
```

There is may be something to change on this line.
And here production.js

```
{ "host": "api-feathers-app.feathersjs.com", "port": "PORT" }
```

Answer (score 1):

As already pointed out you can add the MongoDB URL to your `production.json` in the `mongodb` property. Heroku will also set the `MONGODB_URI` for most MongoDB addons which you can use by changing `production.json` to::

```
{ 
  "host": "api-feathers-app.feathersjs.com", 
  "port": "PORT",
  "mongodb": "MONGODB_URI"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you log into mlab and go to your database you should see a connection string. At the bottom of your `production.json` you should add a line to connect to the mlab database.

Something like:

```
{ 
  "host": "api-feathers-app.feathersjs.com", 
  "port": "PORT",
  "mongodb": "mongodb://USERNAME:PASSWORD@ADDRESS-AT-MLAB:PORT/DB_NAME"
}
```

That last line will be provided to you in the mlab settings. In addition mlab may require some query string at the end of the mongodb url, such as `?ssl=true`. But they will tell you what is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Log in to your mlab account and create a new environment if not created already.

Then click on the database name. It will show you tab containing Collections, Users, Stats, Backups and Tools.

Click on the Users tab and it will show you a list of users assigned to that db. If you haven't created a user for that, then you will have to create a user by clicking on the "Add database user" button.

Once the user has been created you then add this to your `production.json` file. Add this as the value to the `mongodb` key in `production.json` file

```
mongodb://<dbuser>:<dbpassword>@ds115749.mlab.com:15749/<dbname>
```

replace the `<dbuser>` with the database username you created earlier and `<dbpassword>` the password associated to the `dbuser` and replace  with the name of the database you are trying to access.

Here's a full code base for the `production.json` file

```js
{
  "host": "https://your.domainname.com/",
  "port": "PORT",
  "public": "../public/",
  "paginate": {
    "default": 10,
    "max": 1000
  },
  "mongodb": "mongodb://<dbuser>:<dbpassword>@ds115749.mlab.com:15749/<dbname>",
  
}
```

Please note, `default.json` is for your development environment while `production.json` is for your production and used when you are deploying file in the same directory.